# deleting the records with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a example script for confirmation alert while deleting record. I am trying to do it in some animated way. But it is not working properly. Here is the code

HTML code for button to delete

```
<a href="delete1.php?id=1"><button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm" id="danger-alert">Click me</button> </a>
```

script is like

```
 $('#danger-alert').click(function () {
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                type: "error",
                showCancelButton: true,
                cancelButtonClass: 'btn-default btn-md waves-effect',
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger btn-md waves-effect waves-light',
                confirmButtonText: 'Danger!'
            });
        });
```

I am not getting where i should put the delete1.php file in the script.

Comment: what is `swal` ??

Comment: You need an ajax request inside your function to send the request to your php script. Also you don't need to wrap your button in an anchor tag the button is triggering the function.

Comment: What frameworks / libraries are you using?

Comment: Swal is a js library for alerts. http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Comment: yes, swal is for alerts.

Comment: @OrlandoP.: i will try this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

call `delete1.php` with ajax in callback function

```js
 $('#danger-alert').click(function() {
   swal({
     title: "Are you sure?",
     text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
     type: "error",
     showCancelButton: true,
     cancelButtonClass: 'btn-default btn-md waves-effect',
     confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger btn-md waves-effect waves-light',
     confirmButtonText: 'Danger!',
     closeOnConfirm: false,
     closeOnCancel: false
   }, function(isConfirm) {
     if(isConfirm) {
       // do ajax
       $.ajax({
         url: 'delete1.php?id=1',
         success: function(response) {
           swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
         }
       })
     }
     else {
       swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">
<button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm" id="danger-alert">Click me</button>
```